# How to position input onFocus so that it won't stay behind the keyboard [React-Native]

Tags: ios, input, reactjs, react-native

I am having difficulties with forms in my react-native ios app. I want my inputs to position themselves onFocus so that they will be visible when keyboard opens. I used **scrollResponderScrollNativeHandleToKeyboard** which was recommended in other issues, but it is really buggy. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

```
inputFocused(refName) {
   let scrollResponder = this.scrollView.getScrollResponder();
   scrollResponder.scrollResponderScrollNativeHandleToKeyboard(
   ReactNative.findNodeHandle(this[refName]),
     270,
     true
   );
}
```